# Is there a way to get iOS 7 simulator on Xcode 8 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode8

I just updated my Xcode to beta version (8.0) and I lost the iOS8 prior simulator that I had in the previous version. I still need the iOS 7 SDK and iOS 8.Appreciate any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The iOS 7.1 Simulator runtime is not supported on macOS 10.11 and newer.  Xcode 8 requires macOS 10.11 or newer. Thus they are not compatible based on the host OS requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. I have macOS 10.12.1 and XCode 8.2.1.. From answer is obvious that to this XCode there is no way how to get iOS 7.1 simulator. But I'm not sure what happens when I install XCode 7 to my machine? Would I be able to install iOS 7.1 simulator to XCode 7 and build and run my application in debug mode in iOS 7.1 simulator?

Comment: No.  The iOS 7.1 Simulator runtime is not supported on macOS 10.11.  It doesn't matter what version of Xcode you install.  The iOS 7.1 Simulator runtime only works on OS X 10.8, 10.9, and 10.10.

Comment: I also tried to run app on device with iOS 7, and XCode showed me error "Could not locate device support files. This iPhone 4 is running iOS 7.1.2 (11D257), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."

Comment: is it possible to run a .app that is made for iOS 10 on iOS 8 or  7 ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43658414/7621990

Answer (score 1):

No,this is no way to install iOS7 in Xcode 8, because they are different runtime