# xcode 8 not include ios 10 simulators

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I want to debug with iPhone 7 simulator but not showing. How can i download iOS 10 simulators ? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are launching Xcode 8?

Comment: Yes launching with xcode 8 @Desdenova

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 10 only has support back to iOS 8.  [It doesn't have iOS 7 (or earlier) simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091801/is-there-a-way-to-get-ios-7-simulator-on-xcode-8-beta).

Furthermore, Swift 3 (if you're coding with that) [only seems to work with iOS 8 and newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414469/do-xcode-8-swift-3-apps-run-on-ios-7-successfully).