# simulator .app for ios 10 not working in ios 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-simulator, ios10

Basically I ran my project into iOS 10 and copied the .app from there and tried to run it on iOS 8 simulator on a different machine but its not getting installed.

But ideally it should get installed and run perfectly.

so ios 10 simulator .app is compatible with only iOS 10 for iOS 8 we again have to run it on iOS 8 simulator and copy it over

can anybody put some light on this problem

Comment: What is the target OS of your project?

Comment: Target is 8.0 and i don't have problem in iOS devices just with simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the app's deployment target appropriately and properly handle the usage of API that is not available in the oldest OS that you intend to support.

Comment: let say if app deployment target is 7.0 and i ran it on the iOS 7 simulator and If I pass the .app and try install the app on iOS 9 simulator...will it work ? ... Can i assume that It'll work on ios 10 simulator as well ..

Comment: yes.  That's the entire purpose of deployment target and binary compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for confirming

Comment: Nice meeting you . I was never aware that you were working for apple

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem I have never experience this and I was able to run the app on iOS 8,9 and 10.